# UIWebview javascript injection too slow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I need to inject javascript into basic links menu to mark currently selected menu item with different color. Code used:

```
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');for(var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++){var link = allLinks[i];if(link.toString().indexOf(\"%@\") != -1){link.setAttribute(\"class\", \"active\"); break;}}", currentURL];


    [self.topNavigationBarWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jsString];
```

And is called from webviewdidfinishloading. However it tooks really long time to evaluate this chucnk of javascript, webview is already loaded for a long time, but js injection takes 2-3 additional seconds.

Comment: Why not use the native UI components for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a complaint or a question? If its a question what is the question exactly?

If you were wondering if there's any other way of executing Javascript than this, no there isn't.

You can't speed stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString up as its a built in function.

The only options are to 
a) Execute your javascript after the dom has loaded rather than wait for the page to load to see if it gives the appearance of being faster
b) evaluate/changeO\ your javascript to see if it is optimal or it can be made more efficient, can you remove the for loop?